# Adding a column of type DataTable to a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, types, datatable, datacolumn

I'd like to add a `System.Data.DataColumn` to a `System.Data.DataTable` with the type `System.Data.DataTable` using Visual Basic. I don't know the synthax to do that.

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Test", System.Type.GetType("System.Data.DataTable"))) 'this is not correct
```

Can anybody tell me the correct synthax?

Thank you,
Jan

Comment: Are you want to nest 2 `DataTable` instances? This issue may similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960728/problem-while-nesting-datatable.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: ...or rather why do you *think* you need to do that?

Comment: We're using a robot software called `BluePrism` based on dotNet. This software only provides standard data types and DataTables. The possibilities in this software are very limited so I need that for getting a more complex data type. But I found a solution: `dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Test", dt.GetType()))`